# Can we read value of a variable in a class using KSP?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-symbol-processing

I have a class which has some variables, can we use kotlin symbol processing api to somehow read the value of the variable declared in the class?

```
resolver.getDeclarationsFromPackage("com.example")
            .filter { it is KSClassDeclaration }
            .iterator().forEach {
                val cls = it as KSClassDeclaration
                cls.getDeclaredProperties().first()
                }
```

Comment: I assume you're referring to a value set at declaration?  Could you give a sample of the code you're trying to parse?

Comment: Suppose, I have a variable val name = "test". Now I would like to read the value of name declared in the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, KSP doesn't provide the functionality to read the content of the values. However, an exception to this limitation is for Annotation classes, where you can read the arguments values.